# ¿Cómo consigo habilitar un TextBox si está encendido un check button?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, formularios, radiobutton

De antemano muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta.
Me encuentro realizando un formulario en `asp.net framework` para vincular una nueva persona a mis contactos pero cuando le pido al usuario en el formulario que me indique  si  cuenta con empresa dispongo de 4 `<asp:RadioButton>` y un asp:TextBox preguntando si es privada, oficial, mixta u otra.
Mi idea es que en el `<asp:TextBox>` me escriban qué tipo de empresa es, si es que seleccionan el boton de **Otra**. ya intente de varias formas con `JavaScript` pero no lo consigo, es posible que alguien me pueda indicar como debo hacerlo?
Muchas gracias!

**Código de controles:**

```
<div class="grupo2 " style="margin: 0 0 0 2rem">
<b>
  <asp:Label Text="Tipo de Empresa" runat="server"></asp:Label></b>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div>
     <asp:RadioButtonList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="MRadio" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 1rem">
       <asp:ListItem ID="Privada" Value="Privada">Privada</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem ID="Oficial" Value="Oficial">Oficial</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem ID="Mixta" Value="Mixta">Mixta</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem ID="Otra" Value="Otra">Otra</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OtraEmpresa" runat="server" Width="100" placeholder="Cuál?"></asp:TextBox>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Intento que no me funcionó con JavaScript:**

```
function OtraCheck() {
    var btnOtra = document.getElementById('Otra');
    var txtBox = document.getElementById('OtraEmpresa');
    if (botonOtra.checked == true) {
        txtBox.disabled = false;
        txtBox.className = '';
        txtBox.focus();
    } else {
        txtBox.disabled = true;
        txtBox.className = 'disabled';
    }
}
```

**Descripción gráfica del fragmento que tengo:**
[image: esta es la imagen de refencia]

Comment: Al seleccionar `Otra` que debe pasar?

Answer (score 1):

No se en asp, pero con javascript podrías añadir un eventListener al hacer click en el radio y al cambiar la selección, habilitar o no el textbox.

Añadiria un id al radiobuttonlist para poder seleccionarlo

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="empresa" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="MRadio" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 1rem">
```

luego en el script

```
var txtBox = document.getElementById('OtraEmpresa');
var radioEmpresa = document.getElementById('empresa');
empresa.addEventListener("onChange", fnHabilitar);

function fnHabilitar(e){
    if(e.target.value === "Otra"){
        txtBox.disabled = false;
        txtBox.className = '';
        txtBox.focus();
    } else {
        txtBox.disabled = true;
        txtBox.className = 'disabled';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado, al parecer, la referencia de `btnOtra` en el **if** no coinciden.

Por otro lado, la función `OtraCheck()` donde se le llama? Si no se le llama ningún lado, puedes llamar al final.

Debería ser de esta manera:

```js
            
function OtraCheck() {

let btnOtra = document.getElementById('Otra'); 
let txtBox = document.getElementById('OtraEmpresa'); 

if (btnOtra.checked == true) { 
    
    txtBox.disabled = false; 
    //txtBox.className = ''; 
    txtBox.focus(); 
    
} else { 
    
    txtBox.disabled = true; 
    //txtBox.className = 'disabled'; 
}

};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Otra" onclick="OtraCheck()">
<input type="text" id="OtraEmpresa" runat="server" width="100" placeholder="Cuál?" disabled>
```

Este ejemplo puse en `html` para demostrar aquí su funcionamiento.

El `input` puede ser de tipo radio o checkbox sin problemas (solo cambia el diseño).

El `input` de texto debe contener el evento click en ella (en línea) y también el atributo `disabled`; de la siguiente manera:

```
<input onclick="OtraCheck()" disabled>
```

Comment: ya lo intente pero no me funciona, no se que pueda ser, no se si tenga algo que ver que lo estoy realizando en un módulo de DotNetNuke pero con la misma lógica de ASP.net, afecte la sintaxis o algo por el estilo pero ya lo intente corrigiendo el error de referencia de btnOtra y no me funciona tampoco.
La idea es que al seleccionar el ``radioButton`` **Otra** se active el campo ``textBox``, si conoces otra manera de realizarlo estare agradecido!

Comment: @AndresVargas edite mi respuesta para que le eches una revisada